# Retrying failed file uploads to AWS S3

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use [TransferManager.upload(String bucket, String key, File file)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#upload(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) to upload a moderately-sized file (around 10 MB) to my AWS S3 bucket from an Android app.

The following code works intermittently:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(...);
mTransfer = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
mTransfer.upload("bucket", key, file);
```

About half the time, this works great. The other half of the time, the upload fails because of an `SSLException`. Is it expected that uploading to S3 would be this unreliable? Should I be handling retries in the client code?

```
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765): Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0xa1ef1c00: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0xa1ef1c00: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:794)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.android.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:73)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:116)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:44)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink.write(HttpConnection.java:310)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:116)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:131)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.write(UrlHttpClient.java:172)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:129)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:65)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:353)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4234)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1644)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:134)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:126)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.upload(UploadMonitor.java:182)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:140)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:54)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-25 18:27:50.326: I/AmazonHttpClient(10765):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this usually occurs when the network is very spotty.  You may also encounter a Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "YOURBUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname.  There is unfortunately not a lot the SDK can do.  It has automatic re-tries built in, but in the case of a spotty connection this may happen many times and eventually the SDK will give up.  You can re-try the request again, but if that helps or not is really up to the network strength.

Weston